# Accessibility Service onKeyEvent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, accessibilityservice

I'm trying to mute all sounds threw Accessibility Service, is that possible?

if not can I manage the volume keys? I am currently using onKeyEvent to get all volume
key events, and it is working fine but I would like to disable the volume keys in a certain condition and enable them in other condition. I have failed to make this happened because it behaves in a strange way which don't listen to my condition and either works or not.
The following code is an example of what I got:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    if(CONDITION) {
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
                return false; // Volume key shouldn't work
            }
            return true; // execute key normally
        }
    }
    return true; // Volume key should work
}
```

in this case the volume keys don't work no matter what the CONDITION is.
and if I change one of the returns to return super.onKeyEvent(event) suddenly the volume key work all the time despite the CONDITION :(
I don't know what to do

Please Help,
Any advise would help.

**Thanks in advance!:)**

Comment: Your true/false condition is incorrect. From the official web, it said 
"If true then the event will be consumed and not delivered to applications, otherwise it will be delivered as usual."

Comment: So if you don't want the volume up/down events to be taken care by system, you shall return true to "consume" it. REF: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#onKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent)

Comment: @AndroidNewbieA Hey, I tried it both ways and it didn't work but after debugging I figured the problem was it running twice once on action = ACTION_UP and once on ACTION_DOWN so the volume keys always worked. after changing it to consume both actions it finally worked. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Hey the problem was that the function only consumed the action = ACTION_UP while it triggers both action_up and action_down so the volume keys always worked, now I have changed it to consume both actions and it works! the code is:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    if(CONDITION) {
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP || action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
                return true; // Volume key don't work
            }
        }
    }
    return false; // Volume keys work
}
```

Hope it helps anyone. :)